# Defining delegate function in separate file (instead of in ViewController)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a ViewController, and a UIView.
The UIView has a delegate, and the delegate function is set in the ViewController.

**All I want to do, is have the delegate function defined in a separate file.** So the UIView.m #imports the separate file, instead of all the ViewControllers which use the UIView.

I believe this is a standard procedure, but keep falling over myself trying to get it to work. :| Would really appreciate some help. Thanks.

**myViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myUIView.h"
@protocol ModalViewDelegate                     
-(void)didReceiveMessage:(NSString *)message;   
@end
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <ModalViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) myUIView *myUIViewItem;
@end
```

**myViewController.m**

```
#import "myViewController.h"
#import "myUIView.h"
@interface myViewController ()
@end
@implementation myViewController

@synthesize myUIViewItem;
- (void)didReceiveMessage:(NSString *)message { //<<< THIS IS WHAT
    NSLog(@"Message from button: %@", message); //<<< NEEDS MOVING
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
…
myUIViewItem.delegate = self;
…
```

**myUIView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol ModalViewDelegate;
@interface myUIView : UIView {
    id<ModalViewDelegate> delegate;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<ModalViewDelegate> delegate;
```

**myUIView.m**

```
#import "myUIView.h"
#import "myViewController.h"
@implementation myUIView
@synthesize delegate;
...
[delegate didReceiveMessage:@"Data from UIView!"];
```

Comment: The way which you are doing looks good, what is your question?

Comment: Do you want to get the function 'didReceiveMessage' to be implemented in myUIView.m file..

Comment: I want to have the function 'didReceiveMessage' defined in a SEPARATE file. So that I don't have to repeat it in every ViewController that uses the UIView and delegate. e.g. ModalViewDelegate_Action.h and ModalViewDelegate_Action.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I want to have the function 'didReceiveMessage' defined in a SEPARATE
>   file. So that I don't have to repeat it in every ViewController that
>   uses the UIView and delegate. e.g. ModalViewDelegate_Action.h and
>   ModalViewDelegate_Action.m

The way I was given was to use a subclass, and that's been working great for me. In my iOS projects I have a class called BaseViewController, which is a subclass of UIViewController. I put lots of code in it related to HUD management, NSOperations management, etc. Then virtually all my view controllers are subclasses of it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I might look into it if I can't get sree's suggestion working. But I thought that it wasn't recommended to subclass a subclass?

Comment: You are completely mistaken - you can continually subclass to inherit the super class's behavior. In my app I have at one point 4 UIViewController subclasses - the BaseClass, a table controller class, then a Pull-To-Refresh class (the later makes it easy for me to adopt PullToRefresh in multiple places.)

Comment: 4 days later... many thanks for the great advice David H. Sree's solution did not help in the end, but your tip has been most useful.

Comment: You can always unselect his answer as the chosen one, and select mine :-)

Answer (score 2):

well, there is one method actually,

Just take one .h file and lets say `connectionDelegate.h` and declare your protocol init

In  connectionDelegate.h:

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  
     @protocol ConnectionDelegate
     -(void)getResult:(NSString*)_result;
     @end
```

Then in your view controller:

```
 #import "ConnectionDelegate.h"

 @interface myViewController : UIViewController <ConnectionDelegate>
{
 id delegate;
}
```

then in .m file, by just call the method

```
[delegate getResult:_result];
```

**Edit** regarding the warnings:

You need to declare the method in view controller, you need to do like this.

```
 [self getResult:urlDataString];

-(void)getResult:(NSString*)_result{
    [delegate getResult:_result];
}
```

Comment: In the ViewController.m I am getting these errors:  ! Method 'getResult:' in protocol not implemented
! Incomplete implementation    Any idea what I'm not implementing?

Comment: have you declared property for the delegate? @property (nonatomic,retain)    id delegate;

Comment: No, you need to declare it in viewController.h file

Comment: I think it is almost working... I get these two warnings:  1. Method 'getResult' declared here [ConnectionDelegate.h error]
2. Required for direct or indirect protocol 'ConnectionDelegate'  [ViewController.h error]   Any ideas? Thanks for your help sree.

Comment: That warning is because you haven't declared this method -(void)getResult:(NSString*)_result; in your view controller.watch my EDIT

Comment: There was some confusion because in my demo the UIView has the delegate, not the ViewController. But your suggestion works, and I think it will solve my issues. Many thanks for you help sree!